# Servlet Filter not initializing

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm creating a servlet filter for my service and it seems like init() is not being called based on the logs.

I don't have a web.xml file, rather I added a @Provider annotation to the filter class.

```
@Provider
@WebFilter("/*")
public class TestFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        log.debug("Test filter has been initialized");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HeaderMapRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HeaderMapRequestWrapper(req);
        String remote_addr = request.getRemoteAddr();
        requestWrapper.addHeader("remote_addr", remote_addr);
        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response); // Goes to default servlet.
    }

    @Override public void destroy() { }
}
```

Also added to my module:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public void getTestFilter() {
    return new TestFilter()
}
```

Looks at the logs, it seems like the init() is never called. Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you share the logs ?  Link for reference https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html#init(javax.servlet.FilterConfig)

Comment: @saurav I don't see anything in the logs other than the provider instance being registered.

Comment: The `@Provider` is marking this as a JAX-RS artifact, which is not, this is a servlet filter. Remove the `@Provider`.